# Perl CGI::Session cookie for login safety

Tags: perl, security, cookies, authentication, cgi

Once passwords match my login script on Apache do print this cook:

```
my $session = new CGI::Session();
$session->param("~user", $user_name);
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>$session->name, -value=>$session->id, -domain=>'');
print $session->header(-cookie=>$cookie, @_);
```

Then on every other script, after checking that session is not expired or empty i do give access and i check for login USERNAME with this code:

```
my $session = CGI::Session->load();
$loggd_user = $session->param("~user");
```

Then $loggd_user has access to all the data related to his username. But what happens if one modifies the cook to another username? Is it possible? Will one have access to someone else data? Any other security issue with this code or is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an explanation of the security on the back end which can answer some of these questions at:
https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial#SECURITY

The only thing passing back and forth with CGI::Session is a session ID.  All of the information about the session is saved on the server (wherever you choose -- please make it somewhere that the web server will not serve!).  The security of that data depends on how the server is configured, what options you're using with CGI::Session, etc.

It's not clear if you're verifying the IP.  If you aren't, and anyone gets a hold of the session ID of a valid session, they can hijack it and pretend to be that person.  It's trivial to fake cookies because they're just header fields, which can explicitly be set.  The difficulty is faking a valid session ID in the cookie.

Since you're using cookies for the session, the browser keeps track of them for the client and re-sends them to the server every time you visit the page.  This opens the door for cross site request forgery if you don't have a secondary means of identifying the client aside from the cookie.  Even checking the IP doesn't prevent against CSRF.

You should expire these cookies at some point, and I don't just mean on the server side.  The cookie should have an expiration date so the client deletes it's cookie about the session so it will stop sending it.  I'm not sure how that's done in CGI::Session, but I didn't look at more than the tutorial.

And, if your server is accepting unencrypted connections for things that require authentication where you send a password, or when you're passing the session token back and forth, you're begging for trouble.

This is not to be interpreted as a complete list of potential security issues with this method.